# Find distance to middle of line

Tags: math, vector, coordinates

So I have a line, connecting two points, and I want to give this line a visual name in my canvas. I want this name to be positioned right at the middle of the line but with an offset so that the text doesn't go through the line. Determining the middle of the line isn't that hard you can just find it out like that:

[image: formula of middle point]

And the line equation of the normal to the line can be determined pretty easy too:

[image: line equation]

Where you can find out `n` just by inserting `P` into the equation.

Now to the problem: For a given distance to the line, I want to find a point `P(xn, yn)` that is on that normal to the line through the middle of the line. After inserting the linear function into the distance formula I end up with this:

[image: formula for P(xn, yn)]

Not only am I not able to transform this equation to get a valid value for `xn`, I believe there has to be an mathematically easier way to achieve this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about math and not programming, which should be on [math.se]

Comment: Your first formula is wrong, and the *easier way* is to use use vector algebra and stop thrashing around with `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line middle is

```
mx = (x1 + x2)/2
my = (y1 + y2)/2
```

Line length is

```
len = sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)
```

Normalized direction vector of the line is

```
dx = (x2-x1) / len
dy = (y2-y1) / len
```

Perpendicular vector is

```
nx = -dy
ny = dx
```

Point at offset `d` from middle is

```
px = mx + d * nx
py = mx + d * ny
```

or for other side

```
px = mx - d * nx
py = mx - d * ny
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, that helps me a lot. I think at your fourth equation, second row, it should be  'ny = dx' instead of a 'dy = dx'

Comment: Exactly, corrected